# The right hand side of two-column bootstrap grid is covering when resizing window

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

You can try this full code on your computer. When I resize my Chrome and Firefox, the right hand side (which is column 2) will overrun the left hand side.

In jsfiddle this is harder to observe but if you want to: http://jsfiddle.net/kkmzkkyq/5/

It seems like this is caused by my `col-xs-12` but isn't that used if I want a stack behavior?

Second problem is when I resize the window I can also see the right hand side continue (the text is not done!) How do I fix that? Am I supposed to apply text wrap?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>robots.txt scanner demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- CSS are mainly based off
     http://tech.deepumohan.com/2013/09/javascript-ace-editor-positioning-bootstrap.html
     ACE editor CSS is a pain to work with....
-->
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
.right {
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    background: #708090;
    color: black;
}

.left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

#editor {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 left">
            <div id="editor"></div>
        </div>
        <div class ="col-xs-12 col-md-4 right">
            <h1>ewkrwkjrkwejlrjwrwerjwlkrjwlr1111</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
        src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.3/ace.js">
</script>
</script>


<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/chrome");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/text");
    editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
    editor.setOptions({
        fontSize: "13pt",
        useWorker: false
    });
    editor.session.setOption("useWorker", false);
    function resizeAce() {
      return $('#editor').height($(window).height());
    };
    //listen for changes
    $(window).resize(resizeAce);
    //set initially
    resizeAce();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read the docs again. Each row ads to 12 if more than twelve, after each 12 a clearing with a responsive utility class. If you make column classes position absolute, then you will not get the desired result. Do not change the function of the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest problem is that you're not including the bootstrap3.0.2.js file - the css alone is not enough.
Secondly - the grid "bubbles up" - so if you define `col-xs-12` and no col value for `"sm"` you will get 12 as the col value for sm size screens. So you could do a `col-sm-8` and remove the col-md-8.
You also don't need to add left or right as your classes. Here's a good explanation of the grid: http://scotch.io/bar-talk/understanding-the-bootstrap-3-grid-system

And here is the body of your html: you have some messy (closed but never opened) script tags - and I added the include for the bootstrap JS file.
You still have to address the text issue (it's not being wrapped because there are no white spaces I would expect.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
            <div id="editor"></div>
        </div>
        <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <h1>ewkrwkjrkwejlrjwrwerjwlkrjwlr1111</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script 
        src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<script 
        src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.3/ace.js"></script>


<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/chrome");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/text");
    editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
    editor.setOptions({
        fontSize: "13pt",
        useWorker: false
    });
    editor.session.setOption("useWorker", false);
    function resizeAce() {
      return $('#editor').height($(window).height());
    };
    //listen for changes
    $(window).resize(resizeAce);
    //set initially
    resizeAce();
</script>

</body>
```